# Python encoding utf-8 string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have a unicode string `Ð£ÑÐ»ÑÐ³Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð´Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð²ÐºÐµ` and can't encode it. Well, I can with online decoder - it gives me source encoding: UTF-8 and wanted string 'Услуги по доставке'. But how can i do it with Python 2.7? I tried `encode('utf-8')` and `decode('utf-8')`, but they don't work.

I got this string in xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><Tariff><TariffType>Ð£ÑÐ»ÑÐ³Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð´Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð²ÐºÐµ</TariffType><Total_Dost>1398.3</Total_Dost><T‌​otal_DopUsl>.00</Tot‌​al_DopUsl><Insurance‌​>.00</Insurance><wor‌​th>.00</worth><DP>1-‌​7</DP></Tariff></roo‌​t>
```

This is my code:

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(r.text.encode('utf-8')). 
for node in tree: 
   d = dict() 
   for sub_node in node: 
      d.update({sub_node.tag: sub_node.text.encode("UTF-8")})
```

Comment: Please show a small, complete sample on how you tried to decode it.

Comment: I have this value in dictionary. When I type print d['name'], I get Ð£ÑÐ»ÑÐ³Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð´Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð²ÐºÐµ ;
print d['name'].encode('utf-8') I get the same string ;
print d['name'].decode('utf-8') I get exception UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-19: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: How does the strange string get into the dictionary `d`? With `encode` and `decode` you are only converting a `unicode` type into a `str` and vice versa.

Comment: Try to post a minimal example of the XML here.

Comment: You should [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39275420/edit) these things to your question to make the extra information easier to see

Comment: Maybe this could help:
`a = bytearray(b'Ð£ÑÐ»ÑÐ³Ð¸ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð´Ð¾ÑÑÐ°Ð²ÐºÐµ')`
`print a.decode("utf-8", "replace")`

Comment: No, SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters.

Comment: Do you have a `coding` comment in your python file? What codepage is the python file using? What codepage is the xml file using (this does not have to be the same as the `encoding` attribute of the `xml` tag)?

Comment: In python file # coding=utf-8
In xml - utf-8 encoding (without BOM), but for attribute values - windows-1251